# Транзакция в Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java

Добрый день! Надо ли начинать транзакцию при поиске сущности в базе данных (get(...), load(...))? По сути транзакция не будет иметь здесь смысла. Так?

Comment: Зависит от того, один или несколько клиентов работают с базой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если запрос к БД это фактически только SQL `select`, то оборачивание запроса транзакциями лишено смысла, с одним небольшим уточнением:

Если перед запросом вы не пытаетесь изменить уровень изоляции транзакций. По умолчанию уровень изоляции транзакций обычно установлен в `READ_COMITTED`, то есть будут видимы записи, по которым уже прошел коммит.

В некоторых случаях для ускорения запросов можно пробовать установить уровень изоляции транзакций `READ_UNCOMITTED` (чтение незавершенных транзакций) или наоборот ужесточить требование к изоляции установкой `READ_SERIALIZABLE` (чтение только сохраненных транзакций).

Так вот в этом случае нужно оборачивать `select' транзакциями. Во всех остальных случаях это не имеет смысла.